# Cannot create user and assign role in 3 node replica set using inMemory storage engine - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I have created a 3 node replica set in mongodb. Two nodes are using inMemory storage engine and third one is wiredTiger. I am trying to create a user with role but query execution is hanging. This is the command

```
use Employee
db.createUser({
    user: "mongo-test-user",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [
      {role: "readWrite", db: "Employee"}
    ]
    })
```

Note - I am able to create root user successfully.

Comment: Do you try with root user connected?

Comment: @matthPen yes bit no luck. I was able to create when I had wiredTiger engine replica set.

Comment: don't understand what you want to say, wiredTiger has nothing to do with users. If you already created a user (with right role(s), such as 'root' or 'userAdminAnyDatabase' on your rs, you need to connect with this user to create a new one.